# Can I force hydrate to add attribute to element?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component that handles things differently when rendered on the server (SSR) vs in the browser.

It doesn't assign an ID to elements to "fix" quirky browser in-page anchor navigation (which is handled by JS).

Problem is the ID is not added when the app is hydrated. Is there a way to force hydrate to add ID?

```
class Heading extends Component<HeadingProps, HeadingState> {
  constructor(props: HeadingProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      hover: false,
    }
  }
  render() {
    let _slug = slug(reactNodeToString(this.props.children))
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      return React.createElement(
        `h${this.props.level}`,
        {
          id: _slug,
          style: {
            position: "relative",
          },
          onMouseEnter: () => {
            this.setState({
              hover: true,
            })
          },
          onMouseLeave: () => {
            this.setState({
              hover: false,
            })
          },
        },
        <Fragment>
          <HeadingAnchor show={this.state.hover}>
            <Anchor
              story={this.props.story}
              hashLinkOffset={this.props.hashLinkOffset}
              href={`#${_slug}`}
              title={`#${_slug}`}
              className="heading-anchor"
            >
              {[
                <Fragment key={`#${_slug}`}>
                  <Icon icon={["fas", "link"]} size="xs" />
                </Fragment>,
              ]}
            </Anchor>
          </HeadingAnchor>
          {this.props.children}
        </Fragment>
      )
    } else {
      // SSR-mode
      return React.createElement(
        `h${this.props.level}`,
        this.props.children
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Yes and no.
For first render, no, you can't.
The reason is explained in the React docs about hydration:

> React expects that the rendered content is identical between the server and the client. It can patch up differences in text content, but you should treat mismatches as bugs and fix them. In development mode, React warns about mismatches during hydration. There are no guarantees that attribute differences will be patched up in case of mismatches. This is important for performance reasons because in most apps, mismatches are rare, and so validating all markup would be prohibitively expensive.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

---

So basically, React hydration expects the content being hydrated to be exactly the same in the client. It will try to patch up some stuff, but attributes are the mostly ignored in that matter.

How you solve it then? State.

You should not use `typeof window` checks in your `render` function. Instead, use some state variable like `isHydrated` to be set in the `componentDidMount` phase.

Something like this, in an stripped-down version of your class:

```js
type HeadingProps = {
  level: number;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

type HeadingState = {
  isHydrated: boolean;
}

class Heading extends Component<HeadingProps, HeadingState> {
  constructor(props: HeadingProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isHydrated: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isHydrated: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isHydrated) {
      return React.createElement(
        `h${this.props.level}`,
        {
          id: "hydrated",
        },
        this.props.children
      )
    } else {
      // SSR-mode
      return React.createElement(
        `h${this.props.level}`,
        this.props.children
      )
    }
  }
}
```

The hooks version would be a `setState` being called inside an `useEffect`.
`componentDidMount` and `useEffect` are only called client-side.